# Should we kill off [*-faq] tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, meta-tags, meta-faq

For earlier discussion on this sort of thing:

- [sql-faq tag being propagated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136171/sql-faq-tag-being-propagated): this (June 2012) has led to [sql-faq](/questions/tagged/sql-faq) being removed.
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag: this is from late 2010; back then, it seems to have been approved of. But back then there were various questions which were considered on-topic but are now locked as now unsuitable and kept for historic reasons only. Similarly, various meta-tags were approved of then but are not approved of any more.
- [Special handling for FAQ questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168359/special-handling-for-faq-questions): this one is from February this year but is headed in the opposite direction. [Shog9's answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168538/165654) seems to me to be the best, suggesting basically that having FAQ tags isn't necessary or a good idea. The site's own FAQs are quite close to the contents of the FAQ tag and *are* most frequently asked ones. (I paraphrase; this is not precisely what he says and is my interpretation of his words.)

Well then, the `[*-faq]` and `[*-faq-*]` tags currently in existence are:

- [c-faq](/questions/tagged/c-faq) (done)
- [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)
- <s>[c++-faq-lite](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq-lite)</s> (sorry, this is an actual genuine tag; it should have had a tag wiki to tell me!)
- [perl-faq](/questions/tagged/perl-faq) (done)
- [r-faq](/questions/tagged/r-faq)
- [racket-faq](/questions/tagged/racket-faq) (done)

These are meta tags. And as we all know, meta tags are evil. So, should we burninate them?

Comment: I absolutely want to destroy all of them.  The `c++-faq` tag won't go down easily though.  The `c++faq-lite` is an actual *thing* so it shouldn't go, as it doesn't represent a FAQ on the site.

Comment: Also, the `cookbook` tag is on some of the questions, that needs to go as well.

Comment: @casperOne: hadn't noticed that `c++-faq-lite` was a genuine tag... it needs a tag wiki!

Comment: I don't disagree, but I'm not qualified to write it up.

Comment: `recipe` should probably go too.

Comment: @casperOne: problem with `cookbook` and `recipe` is that they are genuine units of division for some things. Chef looks to use them somewhat like another system might have modules.

Comment: @casperOne: Expect torches and pitchforks. ;)

Answer (score 5):

> [The c++-faq tag won't go down easily though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185165/should-we-kill-off-faq-tags?noredirect=1#comment566829_185165)

Damn right.

The long and short is that many people have tried to bring down the C++ FAQ, I dunno about the others, and all have failed, and for good reason. Much like how the C++ book recommendation question won't die, despite many people's best efforts.

The simple fact is that the purists cry, but these are useful resources that exist for a reason. If we killed the FAQ all that would happen is we would replace existing high-quality questions and answers with a lot of detail with something much worse. The C++-faq tag itself serves the same purpose as any other tag- to organize such reference-quality questions/answers. There is no logical reason to remove it.

Comment: The [`c++` tag sorted by frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=frequent) is, [as observed by Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168538/165654), very good—a better indication of what *is* frequently asked than the `c++-faq` tag. What do you think about that? (I speak as one with not very much C++ experience and none at Stack Overflow.)

Comment: To be frank, those two things haven't seen a fraction of my best effort.  Just sayin.

Comment: 93 followers. If people are actually *using* the tag to help find original, canonical questions & answers, then I'm inclined to let the exception slide.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Followers doesn't equate to anything.  I follow a ton of tags and I never use that functionality.